# DSolve for Matrix Variable

Tags: differential-equations, matrix

## Question

I would like to get Mathematica to `DSolve` for $A(t)$ where $A$ is a matrix, without solving for each component individually. It works naturally for `NDSolve` but not `DSolve` so I am wondering

1. Is it possible for Mathematica to `DSolve` for a matrix variable **without** deconstructing it and `DSolve`ing for each element individually?
2. If so, how? If not, why is it possible with `NDSolve` but not `DSolve`?
3. [m0nhawk](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/2342/m0nhawk) mentioned that Mathematica needs to know the structure of $A$, which would be an issue if there are no initial conditions. But given an initial condition Mathematica has all the information it needs and I must assume this is how `NDSolve` gets the structure of $A$. Is this just a silly oversight in functionality or is there a deeper reason I'm not seeing why such functionality would be problematic?

## Motivation

I have a matrix differential equation of the form $A'(t)=B\cdot A(t)$ with $A(0)=I$ and would like to solve this for $A(t)$. This works perfectly fine with `NDSolve` but not with `DSolve`. For example

```
B[x_, y_, z_] = {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, x, 0, 0}, {0, 0, y, 0}, {0, 0, 0, z}};

NDSolve[{I A'[t] == B[1,2,3].A[t], A[0] == IdentityMatrix[4]}, A, {t, 0, 10}]

DSolve[{I A'[t] == B[1,2,3].A[t], A[0] == IdentityMatrix[4]}, A, {t, 0, 10}]

DSolve[{I A'[t] == B[x,y,z].A[t], A[0] == IdentityMatrix[4]}, A, t]
```

returns

```
{{A -> InterpolatingFunction[object]}}

DSolve[{I Derivative[1][A][t] == {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 3}}.A[t],
A[0] == {{1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}}}, A, {t, 0, 10}]

DSolve[{I Derivative[1][A][t] == {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, x, 0, 0}, {0, 0, y, 0}, {0, 0, 0, z}}.A[t],
A[0] == {{1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}}}, A, t]
```

Seems like a failing that the `NDSolve` works fine but the `DSolve` fails.

## Workaround

I know I can always break $A(t)$ down into
$$A(t)=
\begin{pmatrix}
a
_{11}(t) & a_{12}(t) & \cdots \\
a_{21}(t) & a_{22}(t) & \cdots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

and solve for each $a_{ij}(t)$. This does indeed work

```
A2[t_] = Array[Subscript[a,#1,#2][t] &, {4, 4}];
DSolve[{I A2'[t] == B[x, y, z].A2[t], A2[0] == IdentityMatrix[4]}, Flatten[A2[t]], t]
```

returns

```
{{Subscript[a, 1, 1][t] -> 1, Subscript[a, 1, 2][t] -> 0, 
  Subscript[a, 1, 3][t] -> 0, Subscript[a, 1, 4][t] -> 0, 
  Subscript[a, 2, 1][t] -> 0, Subscript[a, 2, 2][t] -> E^(-I t x), 
  Subscript[a, 2, 3][t] -> 0, Subscript[a, 2, 4][t] -> 0, 
  Subscript[a, 3, 1][t] -> 0, Subscript[a, 3, 2][t] -> 0, 
  Subscript[a, 3, 3][t] -> E^(-I t y), Subscript[a, 3, 4][t] -> 0, 
  Subscript[a, 4, 1][t] -> 0, Subscript[a, 4, 2][t] -> 0, 
  Subscript[a, 4, 3][t] -> 0, Subscript[a, 4, 4][t] -> E^(-I t z)}}
```

but this is, in my opinion, ugly and against the philosophy of Mathematica.

I could make my own `DSolve` e.g.

```
matDSolve[eqs_, mat_, par_] := mat/.DSolve[eqs,Flatten[mat],par]
matDSolve[{I A2'[t] == B[x, y, z].A2[t], A2[0] == IdentityMatrix[4]},A2[t], t]
```

returns

```
{{{1,0,0,0}, {0,E^(-I t x),0,0}, {0,0,E^(-I t y),0}, {0,0,0,E^(-I t z)}}}
```

But doing it correctly and robustly seems like a lot of work for something that, in my opinion, should be native.

Comment: _Mathematica_ need to know the structure of function `A`, so I doubt there is simpler way.

Comment: It can get the structure from the initial condition. Which is what it does for the NDSolve case. Why the asymmetry between NDSolve and DSolve?

Comment: If you haven't already done so, this looks like a good suggestion to [send to Support](https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/?topic=feedback).